# How to list systemd services by memory usage

Tags: systemd, systemd-service

I'd like to see which `systemd` services consume the most amount of memory.

Is there a way to list all running (and/or enabled) systemd services by memory usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enable memory accounting by creating `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/accounting.conf` containing

```
[Manager]
#DefaultCPUAccounting=yes
#DefaultBlockIOAccounting=yes
DefaultMemoryAccounting=yes
#DefaultTasksAccounting=yes
```

Reload after config change.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Watch units (**cg**roups) by memory size.

```
systemd-cgtop -m
```